# Elementary OS becoming very slow on long usage

Tags: release-hera, suspend, power

I'm using Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera on a Toshiba laptop.
Since the couple of days,I've been using Eos for very long periods(~10-12 hours) straight. So,when I'm not using the laptop,I'll simply put it on suspend. After doing this(putting the OS on suspend and turning it back on again) for about 4-5 times,the OS seems very slow. The animations and other operations won't work smoothly, and I'll have to restart the PC. Any Ideas?

P.S:I'm always suspending my PC because I've got some files and web pages open which I don't want to start again from the beginning.

Comment: When it has slowed down, have you checked `top` and `free -m` in the terminal? What applications are open when this happens? Browsers, for example, like to keep taking more and more RAM and sometimes should be closed and re-opened.

Comment: Oh. Could be because of firefox.I normally keep 3-4 windows open,each with 1 or 2 tabs. But,even after closing firefox, the OS remains slow.

Comment: I'd take a look at `top` in the terminal (or htop, which is similar but a better layout - but your OS comes with top by default) and keep an eye on `free -m` to see if you can spot what's taking the resources. That's a very trivial Firefox load for a modern computer.

Comment: Well,sometimes it's firefox and sometimes its xorg. I was amazed that Chrome is less resource hungry than firefox. Is there a way to make the OS fast again? I'm a die-hard firefox user.

Comment: Well, Firefox has a built in task manager. You could start there. The xorg can be anything from maybe a conflicting video driver to any number of things. Do you have hardware acceleration enabled in Firefox? This will sound counterintuitive, but disable it and restart the browser.

Comment: K. I'll try it out. Thank you Anyways. But won't firefox's performance be lowered on disabling it?